# iTextSharp XMLWorkerHelper Font Size

Tags: itext

I'm need to set the font size for the iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml() method.
Or set the document default font side. but I can't seem to find the methods in Document object :/

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(tcTopic.Body))
        {
            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                pdfWriter, doc, stringReader
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the font-size in the HTML content that is being parsed through solved my issue.